# Add to cart button does not appear

Tags: magento-1.9, cart, addtocart

I am working in version 1.9.2.4.

I have a problem with the add to cart button when I am not logged.

It does not appear in the category grid search but in the list view it does.

That happened with the single product view too.

I modified the file list.phtml from `/app/design/frontend/royal/hijo/template/catalog/product`

I remove the code but the problem still existing

```
if(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn() && $total > 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn() && $total > 0)
```

If you removed the above code then It would be a cache issue. Flush the cache. If issue still arrives then truncate log_* tables from the database.